# BindModel returns null when binding to a list/collection (but not when binding to csla collection)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a custom model binder that inherits the DefaultModelBinder that looks like this.

```
Public Class GridFormBinder : Inherits DefaultModelBinder

Public Overrides Function BindModel(controllerContext As System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, bindingContext As System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext) As Object
    Dim result As Object = MyBase.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext)

    'Code to handle special case for grid/List binding.

    Return result
End Function 
End Class
```

The reason I have this custom binder is that I am presenting various list of items in a grid (using devexpress mvc gridview) and I bind the controls in the grid to the list of items.

If I use a class derived from BusinessCollectionBase (from a very modified CSLA framework class) everything works exactly like I want. BusinessCollectionBase derives from a class that looks like...

```
 <Serializable()> Public MustInherit Class BindableCollectionBase(Of T As IBusinessData)
        Inherits CollectionBase
        Implements IBindingList
        Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of T)
```

But if I bind to, say, a class that inherits from `BindingList<Customer>` the `MyBase.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext)` always returns nothing. I have tried various generic and non-generic BCL collections and the BindModel method always returns null.

Is there something I have to do to get the DefaultModelBinder to create and return the model for regular collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the source for DefaultModelBinder and figured out the problem.

In the DefaultModelBinder in the BindComplexModel method if the type is not an array and is a generic IEnumerable ( IEnumerable<>) AND it is an instance of ICollection<>  it will call UpdateCollection.  It cannot populate the collection for all the reasons stated.  Because the count = 0 the UpdateCollection method returns null.  So my classes that derive from ICollection (BindingList for example) will have this behavior.

However my custom collection actually derives from the old CollectionBase class (and it implements the generic IEnumerable seperatly). This means that BindComplexModel does not try to populate the collection and instead just binds to the object as normal.*

Personally I think this is a bug or at least an oversight.  If you are binding to a collection and the form has 0 items (say the user has deleted all the rows) you would get nothing back from the default binding. But shouldn't you just get the collection with zero items? What is the reasoning behind returning nothing? This puts more work on the MVC developer because now they have to check for nothing first.

But anyway this is the reason why.

*And this is also the reason I couldn't get the examples of binding to collections to work with my classes. They are not arrays but neither are they IEnumerable<> or IDictionary<>. Yet another bug I think.